# Replacement for abstract and static function

Tags: c#, static, abstract

problem with abstract and static

How can I declare Function2 in my abstract class (AAbstract)?
Function2 can't be abstract and static.
What can I do?

```
interface IInterface
{
    void Function2();
}

public abstract class AAbstract : IInterface
{   
    //need to be static
    public static void Function1() 
    {
        Function2();
        Function3();
    }

    private static void Function3()
    {
        //do something private
    }       
}

public class myClass1 : AAbstract
{
    private static void Function2()
    {
        //do something private, specific to this class
    }
}

public class myClass2 : AAbstract
{
    private static void Function2()
    {
        //do something private, specific to this class
    }
}
```

I call it :

```
myClass2.Function1();
```

or

```
myClass1.Function1();
```

It only can be called like that. Everything is private except this function.

Comment: I want a common class. used by inheritance. The function2 is different for witch myClass I used. but you always start by Function1. MyClass1.Function1() MyClass2.Function1()

Answer (score 0):

You are never going to be able to call a non-static function Function2 in a sub/concrete class from inside static Function1!

You could do it if you required it be passed in an instance of the concrete/sub class  like so:

```
public static void Function1(IInterface someInstance) 
{
    someInstance.Function2();
    Function3();
}
```

Then you'd call it from the concrete class like this:

```
AAbstract.Function1(this);
```

or even just like this:

```
Function1(this);
```

Comment: technically, passing the interface work/build. What I want its Doing MyClass1.Function1() MyClass2.Function1().

Comment: Since it is a static method you'll have to pass it an instance of an object to get access to instance data.  No matter how you call it. I don't see you geting around the need to pass it "this"

Comment: I think I did it wrong. I used to do it with mustinherit in vb.

Answer (score 0):

I miss-read your code, was function2 in the concrete class static when you first posted?  I was confused by your interface declaration. I don't think your code will compile as AAbstract  needs to provide an implementation of Function2.

If you are trying to override the implementation of function2 in myClass1 and myClass2 (and fulfill the IInterface contract), you can't do that with static methods.

Are you just trying to set up inheritance from a common base?